# App Crashes on Splash Screen throwing Null Pointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, splash-screen

According to Playstore ANR & Crashes the app is throwing null pointer on SplashScreen oncreate. I've checked the functioning and it looks good at my end. Not all phones are crashing however are.

My SplashActivity.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String path = "";
    String banner = "";
    String title = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            Log.e("splash", "from push link");
            path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
            banner = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bannerImage");
            title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
            String link = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(path).toString()));
            String imgurl = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(banner).toString()));
            Log.e("link----", "link--" + link);

            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Push", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            String pushtitle = pref.getString("pushtitle", "");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(pushtitle).append(title).append(",");
            Log.e("pushtitle===========", sb.toString());
            editor.putString("pushtitle", sb.toString());

            String links = pref.getString("link", "");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            sb2.append(links).append(link).append(",");
            Log.e("link===========", sb2.toString());
            editor.putString("link", sb2.toString());

            String imgurlstr = pref.getString("imgurl", "");
            StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
            sb3.append(imgurlstr).append(imgurl).append(",");
            Log.e("imgurl===========", sb3.toString());
            editor.putString("imgurl", sb3.toString());

            editor.commit();
        }
        int secondsDelayed = 1;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                if (path  != "") {
                    Log.e("splash", "path==" + path);
                    intent.putExtra("link", String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(path).toString())));
                }
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
    }
}
```

The playstore crashes report as following.
**java.lang.NullPointerException com.example.app.SplashActivity.onCreate**

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2984)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:3045)   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14
>   (ActivityThread.java)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1642)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:102)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1496)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1386) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   at java.io.StringReader. (StringReader.java:50)   at
>   android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert (Html.java:758)   at
>   android.text.Html.fromHtml (Html.java:245)   at
>   android.text.Html.fromHtml (Html.java:188)   at
>   com.example.app.SplashActivity.onCreate (SplashActivity.java:27)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6955)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1126)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:2927

EDIT: Debugging the App I got the below error:

Log messages will follow once session has started...

> I/art     ( 3818): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) W/art
>   ( 3818): Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86 W/System 
>   ( 3818): ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.app-1/lib/x86 D/FirebaseApp( 3818):
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping
>   initialization. W/InstanceID/Rpc( 3818): Found 10012 D/FirebaseApp(
>   3818): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping
>   initialization. I/FA      ( 3818): App measurement is starting up,
>   version: 10084 I/FA      ( 3818): To enable debug logging run: adb
>   shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE I/FA      ( 3818): To enable faster
>   debug mode event logging run: I/FA      ( 3818):   adb shell setprop
>   debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.app I/FirebaseInitProvider(
>   3818): FirebaseApp initialization successful W/art     ( 3818): Before
>   Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable E/splash  ( 3818): from push link
>   D/AndroidRuntime( 3818): Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime( 3818): Process:
>   com.example.app, PID: 3818 E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.SplashActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3818):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3818):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a
>   null object reference E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):    at
>   java.io.StringReader.(StringReader.java:50) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3818):    at android.text.HtmlToSpannedConverter.convert(Html.java:758)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:245)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at android.text.Html.fromHtml(Html.java:188)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   com.example.app.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:27)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3818):  ... 9 more

Comment: I think you are not checking if the values you fetch from intent are null or not and that is what is throwing NPE.

Comment: I've dig into the issue and found this point "com.example.app.SplashActivity.onCreate (SplashActivity.java:27)" checking this line `String link = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(path).toString()));` I see it's mentioned as deprecated code do you think this is causing the issue on Marshmallow and Nougat?

Comment: @7geeky Kindly check the edit update of the question after debugging the app

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && this.getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("yourKey")){
        try {
            Log.e("splash", "from push link");

        path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
        banner = getIntent().getExtras().getString("bannerImage");
        title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        String link = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(path).toString()));
        String imgurl = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(banner).toString()));
        Log.e("link----", "link--" + link);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Push", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        String pushtitle = pref.getString("pushtitle", "");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(pushtitle).append(title).append(",");
        Log.e("pushtitle===========", sb.toString());
        editor.putString("pushtitle", sb.toString());

        String links = pref.getString("link", "");
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        sb2.append(links).append(link).append(",");
        Log.e("link===========", sb2.toString());
        editor.putString("link", sb2.toString());

        String imgurlstr = pref.getString("imgurl", "");
        StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
        sb3.append(imgurlstr).append(imgurl).append(",");
        Log.e("imgurl===========", sb3.toString());
        editor.putString("imgurl", sb3.toString());

        editor.commit();
        } catch (NullPointerException e ) {
            path = "";
            banner = "";
            title = "";
        }
    }
```